# Android: Button two will not play sound unless you press button one first

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to be able to push button 2 without pushing button 1 first to get it to play the sound. This is my code. So if I push button 2 no sound plays until I push button 1

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle LiamIsTheBest) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(LiamIsTheBest);
    setContentView(R.layout.liam);


    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // onClick Method
        // Your Onclick Action Here
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create( MainActivity.this, R.raw.eat);  
              mp.start();

              Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
              play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.play);  
                mp.start();
               }
              });


        }


});

}
      };
```

Xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I want to eat" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I want to play" />
```

<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle LiamIsTheBest) {
    super.onCreate(LiamIsTheBest);
    setContentView(R.layout.liam);


    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create( MainActivity.this, R.raw.eat);  
            mp.start();
        }
    });

    Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.play);  
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // onClick Method
            // Your Onclick Action Here
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                    R.raw.eat);
            mp.start();

        }
    });

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                    R.raw.play);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

You are declaring your play button and setting the `OnClickListener` within the `onClick()` of your first button. You should declare them first and set the `OnClickListener` separately;
Tip: If you are using eclipse, ctrl+shift+f to format your code so you know where your brackets should be.